# How to find out from with application, if rating for app is already done by user

Tags: android, google-play

Form inside my application, I want to give a pop up for user to rate my app. Now I have implemented a dialog box which is prompted every third time user launches the app and asks the user to rate the app. It has two buttons - "rate me" and "No, thanks". If user clicks "rate me", it redirects to my app in google play to allow the user to rate the app.

Now my question is how can I find inside my application if user has rated my app. He may go to google play but do not rate it. What is the best design. Should I stop showing the dialog once user is redirected to my app in Google Play?

Please help me with some suggestions. Thank you

Comment: Use `shared preferences` and stop showing the dialog based on the boolean value stored in `shared preferences`

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318700/how-to-know-if-a-specific-user-has-rated-a-android-app

Comment: @SunilMishra. Thank you for your answer bit it may happen that user goes to my app in Google Play but do not rate it. Is there a way I can query from Google Play if it is rated or not?

Comment: @PramodJGeorge .. Thank you for your answer. The link you suggested me is 2 years old. Does it still hold true or some efficient way of doing it is done by google?

Comment: Why don't you try it? And then you can help perhaps thousands of people by posting an answer? Wouldn't that make you feel good? Consider it a minor dana.

Comment: @MarsAtomic .. Thanks for your encouragement :) I am trying but could not get the solution. If you see my stackoverflow profile, I have given 216 answers and asked 11 questions. I hope it shows that I normally try to answer rather than asking things..still will try more and if i get a solution, will post here

Comment: @Sushil All I was asking was whether you tried the two year old solution yourself because you hadn't indicated whether or not you did so, but now we know. I hope you find what you're looking for, and I wish I had an answer for you.